# Changing class argument from a different class

Tags: python, class, module

I'm working with already written code, that is separated in multiple modules with different classes. I have to connect two classes from separate modules.
The code is long so I will try to explain my problem with a simple example. Lets say I have a `mod1.py` with `Class1`

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self, name='Tim'):
        self.name = name
```

and `mod2.py` with `Class2`

```
class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
                ...
    my_name = 'Jack'
    new_class = Class1(name=my_name)
                ...
    my_name = 'Nic'
```

So my question is, can I somehow change `self.name` in `Class1` when `my_name` changes in `Class2`. I don't want to create a new class with new `my_name`, but actually change it in `new_class`.
I hope my example and question make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class1` doesn't know anything about the variable `my_name`; it only knows that it receives a *value* `'Jack'`, not where that value came from.

Pass an instance of `Class1` to be stored inside an instance of `Class2`. Then any modification of the `Class1` instance will be visible inside `Class2`.

```
class Class2:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c

c1 = Class1("Jack")
c2 = Class2(c1)
c1.name = "Nic"
assert c2.c.name == "Nic"
```